# jQuery: change DOM by clicking a link, after finish loading old DOM is back

Tags: jquery

My problem is I change the DOM with the code below:

`$(".class").click( function() {
  jQuery(".item").css("background", ..
});`

but jquery changes it, before the page is finished loading and than my chanegs are away :(
so what can I do?

`$(document).ready(.. or
$(window).load(..`

does not really help and I didn't find a solution anywhere :-/

thank you for your help :)

Comment: So, you clicking on item when page is not fully loaded?

Comment: class is a menü where I can click elements.
Item should be changed when I click on one of these elements.
 
It changes and when the page is finish with loading, after the click, the changed code is gone (the click code works but this happens before the page is finsish with loading and it gets overwritten after loading :( )

Comment: I think you adding event listener to a link and getting redirected when clicking on it. Try to add return false; over here: $(".class").click( function() { jQuery(".item").css("background", .. ); return false; });

Comment: I cannot change the links, and the menü is big :/ when I only write the return I can't click anymore :o :P